# Unit testing my Presenter that creates a Model in its constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvp, factory-pattern

I am trying to unit test my WinForms application with MVP Passive View implemented. I have created Mock Views and Mock Models so that I can test my Presenters with some data I have set. However, I have run into a problem.

In the constructor of my Presenter, I create my Model. I have thought about eliminating this practice by implementing the Factory Pattern to create my Model without the Presenter knowing anything about the concrete implementation of the Model.

In my unit test, I am trying to test a method from my Presenter(InitializeAssessments) that uses its Model. I want to Presenter to use the Mocked Model there so that there is no connection to a database required and the Presenter just gets the data I set in the Mocked Model. However, since the Presenter creates the 'real' Model, the data is different and my test fails.

Do you think I should implement the Factory Pattern or is there a simple way to fix my issue in the unit testing itsself? Will the Factory Pattern solve my issue?

**EDIT:** For now I am thinking about creating the Model when I construct the Presenter in the View with `homeScreenPresenter = new HomeScreenPresenter(this, new HomeScreenModel());` . So that I only have to reference the IModel in the Presenter itsself, making it easier to test.

**Presenter constructor**

```
public HomeScreenPresenter(IHomeScreenView view)
{
    _model = new AssessmentsModel();
    _view = view;
    _view.InitializingAssessments += InitializeAssessments;
    _view.CreatingNewAssessment += CreateNewAssessment;
    _view.AddingNewStandard += AddNewStandard;
    _view.OpeningAssessment += OpenAssessment;
}
```

**Testclass**

```
[TestClass()]
public class HomeScreenPresenterTests
{
    MockHomeScreenView view;
    MockAssessmentsModel model;
    HomeScreenPresenter presenter;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        view = new MockHomeScreenView();
        model = new MockAssessmentsModel();
        presenter = new HomeScreenPresenter(view);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void HomeScreenPresenterTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(MockHomeScreenView), view.GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(MockAssessmentsModel), model.GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(HomeScreenPresenter), presenter.GetType());
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void InitializeAssessmentsTest()
    {
        model.TestList = new List<string>
        {
            "assessment1",
            "assessment1",
            "assessment2"
        };

        var expectedList = new List<string>
        {
            "assessment1",
            "assessment2"
        };


        presenter.InitializeAssessments(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedList, view.ExistingAssessments);

    }
```

Comment: Why does your model have database connection code inside itself? The model should ideally be a POCO and any DB interaction done through a standard repository pattern/ORM in which you would pass the model into the respective method

Comment: My model calls functions from a static class that connects to a database. It does not use any database-related syntax, but the problem is that I should test the Presenter without connecting to the database whatsoever by using the Mock Model instead.

Comment: It still connects to a database, albeit through a static class and without changing your design, you are stuck with that. You could create some kind of class/method that implements a specific interface which you could then mock within your code.

Comment: What do you mean with 'you are stuck with that'. I see that I now rely on that implementation, but this is code that will not change and is used by many other classes.

Comment: In my view, your model needs to be refactored so that it is simple a POCO. Alternatively, change the constructor of the presenter so that you can pass in an instance of the model, rather than creating it there.

Comment: Yea I thought about that too as you can see in my edit. The only problem with that is that I then create a link between the View and the Model (include the Model namespace in my VIew), which -to my underdstanding of the Passive View MVP- is wrong.

Comment: I do not know about about this pattern, but if you want to create the model in your constructor you need to refactor the code inside the model so that it does not use static methods. You need to be able to create an instance of something, using an interface preferably, which can then be mocked. Not ideal (your model should be dumb in a sense), but will work